# Two column of several divs

Tags: html, css-float

I'm making a 2-column layout with divs.
It should be something like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4976861/html-demo.html

But there is a problem. If content stretches the side blocks vertically, the left blocks shift downwards: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4976861/html-demo-2.html

If I put the sidebar into a wrapper div, it works fine, but it will make the code quiet messy because of the paddings and some background issues which I removed to simplify the demo, so I would like to leave this option for now.

Comment: Can you change the order in which the DIVs are rendered in the Html? My initial thought is that you're probably going to have to wrap either "column".

Comment: I can change the order, but the top content div might be 100% width (like youtube's switchable video size). Either way, if I make a wrapper, I'll have to deal with padding and margins somehow.

Comment: You could absolutely position the top right box, (make sure you relatively position the main wrapper, but you'll have problems with the bottom right box not flowing when the top right box increases in vertical size, I'm assuming that you don't want any of the boxes content to be of a fixed height?

Comment: You're right, each block should be vertically stretchable, so it won't work this way either :(

Comment: Of course I'm presuming that you're trying to keep things simple, so going down the route of setting the position of elements through javascript isn't an option either? I'm not suggestion this is how I would do it, just trying to get an idea of scope.

Comment: Yeah, this would complicate things too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you're going to be able to produce the results that you would like without changing the underlying HTML. You're trying to allow elements to flow (both vertically and horizontally) within the page, but the order in which you have the elements is not going to allow this.

I might be teaching you to suck eggs, but my preference for the HTML output would be something like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="column1">
            <div>left 1</div>
            <div>left 2</div>
            <div>left 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
            <div>right 1</div>
            <div>right 2</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is how I would normally do it, and I believe, this is my only option now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put this under the 2 divs:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to work because of the order in which the elements are rendered. That will just push the bottom two left hand blocks even further down.